# Is it enough to use "group_by" in order to run a grouped linear regression?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, linear-regression

I have about 7000 families in my dataset and for each family I have the income of the parents and the income of their children. Now I want to run a simple linear regression of the parents' income on their childrens' income. However, I need to make sure that this regression is run for each familiy.

example dataset:

```
income_parents <- c(1000, 15000, 4500, 7000, 6500, 2500, 3500, 9000, 1200)
income_children <- c(1200, 7500, 2500, 8000, 5500,  7500, 3250, 7500, 850)
family_name <- c("Miller", "Smith", "Clark", "Powell", "Brown", "Jone", "Garcia", "Williams", "Lopez")

df <- data.frame(income_parents, income_children, family_name)
```

I run the following regression after grouping by the family_name:

```
df_AR <- df %>% group_by(family_name)
AR_1 <- lm(income_children ~ income_parents, data = df_AR)
summary(AR_1)
```

Now I wonder, whether the lm()-function takes the nested data structure into account? If not: How can I change my code that it is taken into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't do what you are hoping. The `lm` method is quite old, and as such it isn't familiar with functionality from newer libraries like `dplyr`.

I believe you can accomplish what you want by adding the family name as an indicator to the model. Something like:

```r
model <- lm(income_children ~ family_name + family_name:income_parents, data = df)
```

This will effectively create a mini-model per family. The first part gives an intercept per family and the the interaction variable gives a slope for `income_parents`.

If you want to stick with the many models approach, you can use [nest](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html).

```r
model_one <- function(data) {
  lm(income_children ~ income_parents, data = data)
}

models <- df %>%
  group_by(family_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, model_one))

models
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# # Groups:   family_name [9]
#   family_name data             model 
#   <fct>       <list>           <list>
# 1 Miller      <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 2 Smith       <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 3 Clark       <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 4 Powell      <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 5 Brown       <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 6 Jone        <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 7 Garcia      <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 8 Williams    <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>  
# 9 Lopez       <tibble [1 × 2]> <lm>
```

You will notice that this output is not very useful yet. It can be summarized neatly with [broom::glance](https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/glance.lm.html), and then unnested. It is not very interesting here because each model only has one data point.

```r
summarized <- models %>%
  mutate(summary = map(model, broom::glance)) %>%
  unnest(summary)

# Drop the still-nested columns for display.
summarized %>% select(-data, -model)
#   family_name r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual
#   <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
# 1 Miller              0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 2 Smith               0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 3 Clark               0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 4 Powell              0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 5 Brown               0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 6 Jone                0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 7 Garcia              0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 8 Williams            0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
# 9 Lopez               0             0   NaN        NA      NA     1    Inf  -Inf  -Inf        0           0
```

For more detail, I recommend the [Many Models](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) chapter of Data Science for R.